# Is there a data visualization library that pulls data from a server such as postgres?

Tags: d3.js, tree, data-visualization, javascript

I'm attempting to build a data visualization project that will function like the dynamic tree [here](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html) and the dynamic tree [here](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example3.html) in that it will interact with the server by adding and deleting notes.

I looked at D3.js, but that would cause all of the data to be stored on the client side, which is not secure and does not travel to the server. I also looked at Python , but it was not dynamic in the manner that I would have liked it to have been.

In practice, here's how the app will work:

1. A single bubble (data node) will be initialized, and will ask the user to put a string in the box.
2. The page will redirect to a page with five smaller nodes attached to the main (first) node. The user will be able to click and invite people to suggest the creation of other nodes (noted by a translucent bubble node on the initial user's page that will say "confirm" or "deny".
3. The new users' (that were invited by the initial user) input will be saved as a translucent bubble node on the main user's account through a **server**.
4. The initial user logs into their account, and can see the translucent bubble data nodes (displayed as a tree and attached to the main node) that were added by the people they invited.
5. The initial user confirms or denies each translucent data node, therefore sending that data to be Created or Deleted (CRUD).

**Is there a library that allows interaction between data visualization and the server such as the creation of nodes and associating them with main nodes?**

Or, what technologies could be used to do this?

Comment: This seems like a pedestrian data binding problem.  The problem isn't solved in the general case for ordinary data-entry forms either, unless you're using something like Angular which has two-way data binding built-in.  In other words, you'll need to write some code.

Comment: That explains why I have not been able to find anything about it. I can use Angular, but how could I integrate that into data visualization and pulling data from postgresql?

Comment: Your question is way too broad for stackoverflow.  Essentially you are asking, "How do I write a web application to visualize data with a database backend?"

Comment: Ok, I was wondering whether it was a specific issue. I'll look into writing this with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

d3 doesn't need to have the data stored on the client side, you can send that either when you load the html page that contains the viz or via ajax call.

If your concern is about transmitting "raw data" from the server to the client, you might want to transmit only the data already aggregated if it's possible for your type of graph, and obviously secure the server so it only gives the data to the authorised users.

However, if you have a visualisation, the end user will be able to re-construct the data from the datavisualisation anyway, so transmitting the raw data isn't a problem either IMO, just makes it slightly easier if the user wants to get the data.

X+